# firebase-crashlytics will get Android_Id, how can I change the timing of getting it, or not get it

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I want to change the timing of getting anroid_id

The following is the call stack:

[com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CommonUtils.isEmulator(CommonUtils.java:406),

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CommonUtils.isRooted(CommonUtils.java:421),

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController.createOsData(CrashlyticsController.java:722),

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController.doOpenSession(CrashlyticsController.java:577),

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController.access$500(CrashlyticsController.java:52),

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$9.call(CrashlyticsController.java:515),

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$9.call(CrashlyticsController.java:512),

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker$3.then(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:105),

com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3),

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167),

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)**strong text**

```
and this is my issue : https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9606
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was addressed here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/pull/3840

You will need to upgrade the Crashlytics SDK version.

Comment: It's too bad ,I use flutter version , Not sure yet which version should I upgrade to (native dsk doesn't support the latest version)

Comment: As far as I know, the latest Crashlytics Flutter SDK should be pointing to the latests Android SDK versions that contain this fix. https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics/changelog